# I can only import the Stripe Python library under a certain version of Python

Tags: python, linux, module, webfaction, stripe-payments

I use Webfaction, and this is the command line for the shared host.

```
[zallarak@web198 ~]$ python2.6
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Nov 23 2010, 02:02:03) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import stripe
>>>

[zallarak@web198 ~]$ python2.7
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Dec  1 2010, 06:29:57) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import stripe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named stripe
```

I know there must be a simple way to make it work in all version of Python. I would much appreciate any insight on how to make this work/the concept behind it.

My version of Django runs on 2.7, so the goal is to make it work on 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the `stripe` module is not installed in each python environment.

> I know there must be a simple way to make it work in all version of Python.

You must install `stripe` in each environment.  According to [your webhost](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/python.html?highlight=python%20module#installing-python-packages), you should be able to install them with `easy_install`.  Try this:

```
python2.7 `which easy_install` stripe
```

Comment: [zallarak@web198 ~]$ python2.7 `which easy_install` stripe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2607, in <module>
    parse_requirements(__requires__), Environment()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: setuptools==0.6c5
Is the response I get.

Comment: Try `python2.7 \`which easy_install\` -U setuptools`.  Then repeat the command above.

Comment: thanks for the help. I did this: [http://community.webfaction.com/questions/6365/problems-installing-pycurl] then ran the install command [pip install --index-url https://code.stripe.com --upgrade stripe] and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Brian Cain is correct about it not being installed in the Python version you are using. Instead of the command he gave you should run:

```
easy_install-2.7 stripe
```

After making sure that the directory: `/home/username/lib/python2.7/` actually exists. If it doesn't you can use the command: `mkdir -p /home/username/lib/python2.7` to create it.

That will install it in your Python2.7 installation, which you can then use from Django on Python2.7.

Note: If you get the error: "Need libcurl version 7.19.0 or greater to compile pycurl." you'll need to follow the instructions here:

http://community.webfaction.com/questions/6365/problems-installing-pycurl

to install your own version of curl on your account.

Comment: Hmm...I'd assume they'd be equivalent.  As far as I can tell, the python2.7 install has a `setuptools` package which does not meet the requirements of the package.  I look forward to hearing the outcome of these experiments.

Comment: For some reason they aren't equivalent:

`[klynton@web98 ~]$ python2.7 
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Dec  1 2010, 06:29:57) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import setuptools
>>> print setuptools
<module 'setuptools' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'>
>>> setuptools.__version__
'0.6c11'
>>> 
`
But as long as the newer version of curl is installed everything else works great:
`Finished processing dependencies for stripe
[klynton@web98 ~]$ python2.7
>>> import stripe
>>> import pycurl
>>> 
`